# What is the VC dimension of the hypothesis class $H=\left\{f_{\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}}: R^{2} \rightarrow\{0,1\} \mid 0<\theta_{1}<\theta_{2}\right\}$?

Tags: learning-theory, vc-dimension

I would like to know what is the VC dimension of the following hypothesis class.

$$H=\left\{f_{\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}}: R^{2} \rightarrow\{0,1\} \mid 0<\theta_{1}<\theta_{2}\right\}$$

where $f_{\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}}(x, y)=1$ if $\theta_{1} x \leqslant y \leqslant \theta_{2} x,$ else $f_{\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}}(x, y)=0$.

I am not really sure how to prove it. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

The VC-dimension of your hypothesis class $\mathcal H$ is 2.
To see this, we begin by showing that $\mathcal H$ shatters any 2-element set $\{(a_1 a_2), (b_1, b_2)\}$ of real numbers where all components of the pairs are positive:

1. $\emptyset$ is accounted for by $f_{c, c + \varepsilon}$ for any real $c$ such that $ca_1 \neq a_a$ and $cb_1 \neq b_2$ and some sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$.
2. $\{a\}$ (and similarly $\{b\}$) is accounted for by $f_{c, c + \varepsilon}$ where $c = a_2/a_1$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ is sufficiently small.
3. $\{a, b\}$ is accounted for by $f_{\varepsilon, c}$ for some sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$ and some sufficiently large $c$ (specifically, one can set $\varepsilon = \min \{a_2 / a_1, b_2 / b_1\} / 2$ and $c = 1 + \max \{a_2 / a_1, b_2 / b_1\}$)

This yields $\operatorname{VC}(\mathcal H) \geq 2$.

Now consider some arbitrary set $X = \{(a_1, a_2), (b_1, b_2), (c_1, c_2)\}$ of pairwise distinct points in $\mathbb R^2$.
If the points in $X \cup \{(0, 0)\}$ are not in [general position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position) then $\mathcal H$ cannot shatter $X$ as it means that there are at least two points $s, t \in X$ which fall onto a line with the origin and as every classifier in $\mathcal H$ has linear decision boundaries it must always label $s$ and $t$ the same way, preventing it from shattering any set containing these points.

So let us assume that $X \cup \{(0, 0)\}$ is a set of points in general position and shattered by $\mathcal H$.
As all functions $f_{\theta, \varphi} \in \mathcal H$ represent areas between two lines with positive slopes (since we require $0 < \theta < \varphi$) we can infer that all the lines connecting points in $X$ with the origin also must have positive slopes (note that $X$ is not in general position when the origin is an element of $X$).
Hence we can order the points in $X$ ascendingly by these slopes, i.e. we may write 
$$ a_2 / a_1 < b_2/ b_1 < c_2 / c_1$$
and since this requires all $x$-coordinates of the points in $X$ to be nonzero, we can simplify the expression for the preimage of $1$ of any $f_{\theta, \varphi} \in \mathcal H$ restricted to $X$ to
$$ f_{\theta, \varphi}|_X(x, y)^{-1} = \{(x, y) \in X \mid \theta \leq y / x \leq \varphi\} $$
by dividing by $x$.
Now consider the subset $X' = \{a, c\}$ of $X$ and suppose $f_{\theta, \varphi} \in \mathcal H$ accounts for $X'$, i.e. $f_{\theta, \varphi}|_X^{-1}(1) = X'$.
But then we must have 
$$\theta \leq a_2 / a_1 < b_2 / b_ 1 < c_2 / c_1 \leq \varphi$$
which yields $f_{\theta, \varphi}|_X(b) = 1$ and thus $f_{\theta, \varphi}$ does not 
account for $X'$ which is a contradiction.
Therefore $\mathcal H$ does not shatter $X$ and and thus no set of size $\geq 3$.

It follows that $2 \leq \operatorname{VC}(\mathcal H) < 3$ and thereby
$$\operatorname{VC}(\mathcal H) = 2.$$

Comment: Thanks for the amazing explanation. Is it easy to make an example with 3 samples that give an intuition of how you proved that it the VC(H) cannot be more than 3?

Comment: For $\operatorname{VC}(\mathcal H) < 3$ we need to show that _no_ such sample exists, so considering examples is not enough. However, the idea here is a geometric one: Note that the set where some $f \in \mathcal H$ is 1 is the area between two lines with positive slopes, so if $f$ is 1 on the two "outer" samples then it must also be 1 on the "middle" sample so it cannot shatter any such set. I wrote a formal proof for this (which is a bit more involved and technical) but the idea is rather simple if you draw up a picture :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, its really helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help out :)

Comment: The two linear functions that bound the area are $\theta x$ and $\varphi x$ with $0 < \theta < \varphi$ required by your definition. If the slope is $> 0$, then it must be positive. The value of $x$ does not play a role for that. However, a linear function $ax$ with a positive slope (i.e. $a > 0$) attains negative values when $x$ is negative.